# Using VBA: Assign value to label control on userform

Tags: vba, excel, controls, userform

I am working in the VBA code behind a userform. I have a string variable named block that corresponds to the name of a text label on my userform.  After looking at other questions it seems using the controls function gives the ability to control the settings of a label on the userform.  The block variable is a string of the labels name.I get an error at all attempts below

```
 Me.Controls(block).BackColor = &HFFFF&
```

When I try to hard code it to make sure it is the exact name of the label I still get an error

```
 Me.Controls("S111").BackColor = &HFFFF&
```

The following line DOES work:

```
 Me.S111.BackColor = &HFFFF&
```

When I try a similar technique I get another error with:

```
Me.block.BackColor = &HFFFF&
```

What am I doing wrong and is what I am doing possible?

Comment: I assume that `block` variable stores value "S111". Am i right?

Comment: `Me.Controls("S111").BackColor = &HFFFF&` works for me.

Comment: `Me.Controls(block).BackColor = &HFFFF&` also works for me

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: You might try iterating all the names of `Controls` and checking against `block` to see if there a simple (but not obvious) mismatch.  Code: `For Each ctl In Me.Controls: Debug.Print ctl.Name = block: Next`.  I see no obvious reason the code wouldn't work which points to `block` not containing what you think it does.

Comment: Is the code actually in the userform's code module? Otherwise the `Me` keyword will not be referring to the user form and will therefore cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control `Me.S111` is an object.

```
Dim objObject as Object '(Not type String)
Set objObject = Me.S111
objObject.BackColor = &HFFFF&
```